# PHP: Preg_match_all to extract html into string

Tags: php, preg-match

I have html like this:

```
  <ul id="video-tags">
            <li><em>Tagged: </em></li>
                    <li><a href="/tags/sports">sports</a>, </li>
                            <li><a href="/tags/entertain">entertain</a>, </li>
                            <li><a href="/tags/funny">funny</a>, </li>
                            <li><a href="/tags/comedy">comedy</a>, </li>
                            <li><a href="/tags/automobile">automobile</a>, </li>
                    <li>more <a href="/tags/"><strong>tags</strong></a>.</li>
  </ul>
```

How can I extract the sports, entertain, funny, comedy, automobile into string

my php preg_match_all look like this:

```
preg_match_all('/<a href\="\/tags\/(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>, <\/li>/', $this->page, $matches);
echo var_dump($matches);    
echo implode(' ', $tags);
```

It does not work.

Comment: How does it 'not work'? What are you getting? Errors? A different string than you expect? What IS it doing (or not doing)? What is `$tags` supposed to be, where is it set?

Comment: my var_dump look like this:
array(3) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } [2]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: im expecting something like: sports, entertain, funny, comedy, automobile showed inside array or string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're getting `$this->page` from, however the following should work as you're expecting:

http://ideone.com/KhWkEg

```
<?php
$page = 'subject string ...';

preg_match_all('/<a href\="\/tags\/(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>, <\/li>/', $page, $matches);

echo implode(', ', $matches[1]);  
?>
```

Substitute the `$page` variable for your `$this->page` so long as it is still a string.

However, I'd suggest [not trying to parse HTML with Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1209423). Instead, use a library like [PHP DOM document](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or [SimpleHTMLdom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to properly parse HTML.

Answer (score 2):

This small regex [does the same thing](http://ideone.com/2Tg7NQ) too.

```
preg_match_all('|tags/[^>]*>([^<]*)|', $str, $matches);
```

Also using DOMDocuemnt.

```
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($str);
$as = $d->getElementsByTagName('a');
$result = array();
for($i=0;$i<($as->length-1); $i++)
    $result[]=$as->item($i)->textContent;

echo implode(' ', $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly for me:

```
preg_match_all('/<a href\="\/tags\/(.*?)\">.*?<\/a>, <\/li>/', $str, $matches);
echo implode(',', $matches[1]);
```

Prints: sports,entertain,funny,comedy,automobile

$this->page is probably empty, that's why you are not getting any data.

Why do you put the brackets twice in regexp? You have the same words both in url and text of the link.